# Android app to print document at specific ip address

Tags: java, android

I have a list of all document files in `RecyclerView`.  Now on touch any element, I want it to be printed at an IP  address.

Comment: You want your app to send deocuments by network to printer and that printer should print documents?

Comment: @Zoffa yeah same as we take print from our pc who is in lan with printer

Comment: ok. do you want to know how to develop such app? or you have it already, and some parts are not working?

Comment: @Zoffa actually i was developing it but i have not idea how to start it so basically i want that only code to print at ip address

Answer (score 0):

Android's printing support is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html). However, it does not allow *you* to specify the printer — the *user* specifies the printer.

If you wish to bypass Android's printing support, contact the printer manufacturer for details of what network protocols that they support, what printer languages (PCL, Postscript, etc.) that they support, and what they recommend for use for printing directly to their printer from your app.